# A quick question from a newbie about deleting non-Upper-alpha: why isn't my code working?

Tags: c++, xcode, new-operator

Hi I am trying to delete all the non-capitalized alphabet from a string input, but I am not quite sure where the error is in my coding. Please comment if you know why!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

string CreateAcronym(string userPhrase) {
int i;
int stringSize;
char charAti;

stringSize = userPhrase.size();

for (i=0 ; i < stringSize ; i++ ) {
   charAti = userPhrase.at(i);
   if ( !isupper(charAti)) {
      userPhrase.erase(i,1);
   }
}
return userPhrase;
}

int main() {
string userSentence;

getline(cin , userSentence);

cout << CreateAcronym(userSentence) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your loop where you `erase` the characters, remember that it will change the length of the string, something which you don't handle. As a possible simpler solution: Consider copying the characters you want to keep to a new string, and return that new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You cached old string length and continued to use while the string will become shorter by erasing characters.
- You skip characters after characters to erase because `i++` isn't canceled after erasure.

```
stringSize = userPhrase.size();

for (i=0 ; i < stringSize ; i++ ) {
   charAti = userPhrase.at(i);
   if ( !isupper(charAti)) {
      userPhrase.erase(i,1);
   }
}
```

should be

```
for (i=0 ; i < static_cast<int>(userPhrase.size()) ; ) {
   charAti = userPhrase.at(i);
   if ( isupper(charAti)) {
      i++;
   } else {
      userPhrase.erase(i,1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues in your code.

First, you are erasing the string inside the loop (which changes its length), but using the precalculated length in the comparison.

Second, you only need to increment `i` when you don't erase a character. Otherwise, you will skip over some characters.

A working loop would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < userPhrase.size();) {
   charAti = userPhrase.at(i);
   if ( !isupper(charAti)) {
      userPhrase.erase(i,1);
   }
   else {
     ++i;
   }
}
```

You could simplify this loop by using an algoritm:

```
string CreateAcronym(string userPhrase) {

 userPhrase.erase(std::remove_if(userPhrase.begin(), 
                    userPhrase.end(), [](auto charAti) { 
                      return !isupper(charAti); }), 
                  userPhrase.end());

 return userPhrase;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TFdmig).

Answer (score 0):

The problem have been answered by others, so I just add my "simpler" solution to the problem:

```
string CreateAcronym(string userPhrase) {
    string result;  // Create an empty string

    // Loop over all the characters in the original string
    for (char c : userPhrase) {
        // If the character is upper-case...
        if (isupper(c))
            result += c;  // Append it to the new string
    }

    return result;  // Return the new string
}
```